# Jquery load into div on toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

Not sure if this is possible but can you load and unload into a div on a jquery toggle?

something a bit like this?

```
$("#IDOFCLICK").live('click',function(){
$(this).toggleClass("active").('#IDOFDIVTOLOAD').load('PAAGETOLOAD').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

if you can I guess the above is not right, but, how would you also unload on the "reverse" toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work. The `toggle` you're using just toggles the class. There is a `toggle` event you could use, but it is not supported by `live()` to my knowledge.

When you say `unload` I assume you want to empty the content of `#IDOFDIVTOLOAD`. If that's right, you could try this:

```
$("#IDOFCLICK").live('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var $loadElement = $('#IDOFDIVTOLOAD');
    if( $loadElement.is(':empty') ) {
        $loadElement.load('PAAGETOLOAD').slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
        $loadElement.empty().slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

---

**jQuery docs:**

- `.is()` - http://api.jquery.com/is/
- `.empty()` - http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: Thanks Patrick will give it a go, I knew mine was totally wrong but I wasn't even sure if it could be done.

Comment: Sounds good. Just a note, the `.is()` won't be right if there was some other content inside `#IDOFDIVTOLOAD` before the load. If that's the case, you'll need to change the test in the `if()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this and when I tried it, there was a little animation that took place before the page was loaded, then the toggle happened. I changed the code in the IF statement to an ajax call to test if the data was loaded before slideToggle. It gave the desired effect.

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "/pagetoload",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $loadElement.html(data);
                            $loadElement.slideToggle("slow");
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert("Error!");
                        }
                    });
```